# Jquery UI not working with calculator

Tags: jquery, calculator

I have this inherited script which I can't get it too work. The person who wrote it is not contactable and I'm a little stuck. Hoping you guys can help me get it to work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
.process-box {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    border-left: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    width: 940px;
    padding: 15px 0;
    margin: 20px auto 0;
 }
 .process-box ul {
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0;
 }
 .process-box li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    background: url('http://www.genata-motor.co.uk/images/red-sep-arrow.png') no-repeat right center;
    width: 170px;
    height: 100px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 56px;
    margin: 0;
 }
 .process-box li.first {
    padding-left: 0;
 }
 .process-box li.last {
    background: none;
    padding-right: 0;
 }
 .process-box li h3 {
    background: #575757;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #575757 0%, #2c2c2c 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #575757), color-stop(100%, #2c2c2c));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #575757 0%, #2c2c2c 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #575757 0%, #2c2c2c 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #575757 0%, #2c2c2c 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #575757 0%, #2c2c2c 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#575757', endColorstr='#2c2c2c', GradientType=0 );
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 28px;
    color: #eee;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
 }
 .process-box li h3 span {
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-right: 4px;
 }
 .calculator {
    background: #f3f3f3 url('http://www.genata-motor.co.uk/images/bg-dotted.png') repeat 0 0;
    border-radius: 30px;
    width: 800px;
    height: 214px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 30px auto 20px;
 }
 .calculator h3 {
    background: #b3b3b3;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #b3b3b3 0%, #777777 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #b3b3b3), color-stop(100%, #777777));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #b3b3b3 0%, #777777 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #b3b3b3 0%, #777777 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #b3b3b3 0%, #777777 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #b3b3b3 0%, #777777 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#b3b3b3', endColorstr='#777777', GradientType=0 );
    border-radius: 25px;
    font-size: 21px;
    line-height: 34px;
    color: #eee;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #666;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
 }
 .ie9 .calculator h3 {
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    filter: none;
 }
 #borrowing-total, #period-total {
    float: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    width: 602px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
 }
 #period-total {
    float: right;
    width: 172px;
 }
 #borrowing-slider-wrap {
    float: left;
    background: url('http://www.genata-motor.co.uk/images/slider-range-sprite.png') no-repeat left top;
    width: 602px;
    height: 28px;
 }
 #period-slider-wrap {
    float: right;
    background: url('http://www.genata-motor.co.uk/images/slider-range-sprite.png') no-repeat -604px top;
    width: 172px;
    height: 28px;
 }
 #borrowing-slider, #period-slider {
    margin: 0 14px 0 13px;
 }
 .ie #borrowing-slider, .ie #period-slider {
    margin: 0 14px 0 12px;
 }
 .ui-slider {
    position: relative;
    height: 28px;
 }
 .ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    top: -4px;
    background: url('http://www.genata-motor.co.uk/images/slider-range-sprite.png') no-repeat right top;
    border: 0;
    width: 17px;
    height: 22px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: -8px;
 }
 .ui-slider .ui-slider-range {
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
 }
 .stat-container {
    width: 750px;
    margin: 25px auto 0;
 }
 .stat-container div {
    float: left;
    background: #6a1d1d url('http://www.genata-motor.co.uk/images/price-gradient.png') repeat-x left top;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #eee;
    width: 210px;
    height: 78px;
    line-height: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
 }
 .stat-container strong {
    display: block;
    font: 38px/54px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
 }
 .stat-container .center {
    margin: 0 60px;
 }
</style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="newcalculator">
                <h3>Personal Loan Calculator</h3>
                <div>
                    <div class="calculator-elements">
                        <div id="borrowing-total"> Amount Borrowing: <strong></strong> </div>
                        <div id="period-total"> Years: <strong></strong> </div>
                        <div id="borrowing-slider-wrap">
                            <div id="borrowing-slider"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="period-slider-wrap">
                            <div id="period-slider"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- calculator-elements --> 

                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <div class="stat-container">
                    <div id="interest"> Interest <strong>&pound;0</strong> </div>
                    <div id="monthly-payment" class="center"> Monthly Payments <strong>&pound;0</strong> </div>
                    <div id="total-repayable"> Total Repayable <strong>&pound;0</strong> </div>
                </div>
            </div>            
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">!window.jQuery && document.write('<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://speedwaymotorcycles.co.uk/js/jquery.ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://speedwaymotorcycles.co.uk/js/jquery.plugins.min.js"></script>

<script>
(function(window, document, $){
    function financePage(){

        var borrowSlider = $('#borrowing-slider'),
            periodSlider = $('#period-slider'),
            borrowNum = $('#borrowing-total strong'),
            periodNum = $('#period-total strong')
            borrowVal = 0,
            periodVal = 0;

        var interestNum = $('#interest strong'),
            paymentNum = $('#monthly-payment strong'),
            repayableNum = $('#total-repayable strong');

        borrowSlider.slider({
            value: 750,
            min: 500,
            max: 4000,
            step: 25,
            slide: function(e, ui){

                var val = ui.value;
                borrowNum.html('&pound;' + val);

                // prevent function mass execution, true = override self
                $.doTimeout('slider', 20, function(){
                    calculateLoan(val, null);
                }, true);
            }
        });
        borrowNum.html('&pound;' + borrowSlider.slider('value'));

        periodSlider.slider({
            value: 2,
            min: 1,
            max: 4,
            step: 1,
            slide: function(e, ui){

                var val = ui.value;
                periodNum.html(val);
                calculateLoan(null, val);
            }
        });
        periodNum.html(periodSlider.slider('value'));

        calculateLoan();

        function calculateLoan(borrow, period) {

            // uses parent variables to stop multiple calls
            var borrow  = (borrow)
                        ? borrowVal = borrow
                        :   (borrowVal)
                            ? borrowVal
                            : borrowVal = borrowSlider.slider('value'),
                period  = (period)
                        ? periodVal = period
                        :   (periodVal)
                            ? periodVal
                            : periodVal = periodSlider.slider('value');

            var totalRepayable = Math.round(((((borrow + 195) / 100) * 10) * period) + borrow),
                monthlyPayment = Math.round(totalRepayable / (period * 12)),
                interest = Math.round(totalRepayable - borrow);

            interestNum.html('&pound;' + interest);
            paymentNum.html('&pound;' + monthlyPayment);
            repayableNum.html('&pound;' + (totalRepayable + 195));
        }
    }    
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LWd26/

(Both sites that link the external files are our customers - were not using the files without permission)

Comment: Please clarify: "get it to work". What's not working?

Comment: The dibbers on jquery UI dont show neither do the prices change. sorry im new to stackoverflow

Comment: link to demo is great...except we don't know what it should or shouldn't do or steps to replicate problems

Comment: Yep - being new is no excuse for writing a question of desperation with not enough detail to highlight the problems you're facing!

Comment: Sorry i know nothing about jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Notwithstanding the lack of useful info in the question from the OP (and ignoring the fact that the poor OP has been left to inherit code that seemingly they cannot understand the basics of) here's the solution.

You just needed to call `financePage()` after loading the page (I've put the javascript into jQuery's `ready` function)

```
$(document).ready(function () { // <-- Added this bit to make sure your document has fully loaded before running any contained javascript
    function financePage() {

        var borrowSlider = $('#borrowing-slider'),
            periodSlider = $('#period-slider'),
            borrowNum = $('#borrowing-total strong'),
            periodNum = $('#period-total strong')
            borrowVal = 0,
            periodVal = 0;

        var interestNum = $('#interest strong'),
            paymentNum = $('#monthly-payment strong'),
            repayableNum = $('#total-repayable strong');

        borrowSlider.slider({
            value: 750,
            min: 500,
            max: 4000,
            step: 25,
            slide: function (e, ui) {

                var val = ui.value;
                borrowNum.html('&pound;' + val);

                // prevent function mass execution, true = override self
                $.doTimeout('slider', 20, function () {
                    calculateLoan(val, null);
                }, true);
            }
        });
        borrowNum.html('&pound;' + borrowSlider.slider('value'));

        periodSlider.slider({
            value: 2,
            min: 1,
            max: 4,
            step: 1,
            slide: function (e, ui) {

                var val = ui.value;
                periodNum.html(val);
                calculateLoan(null, val);
            }
        });
        periodNum.html(periodSlider.slider('value'));

        calculateLoan();

        function calculateLoan(borrow, period) {

            // uses parent variables to stop multiple calls
            var borrow = (borrow) ? borrowVal = borrow : (borrowVal) ? borrowVal : borrowVal = borrowSlider.slider('value'),
                period = (period) ? periodVal = period : (periodVal) ? periodVal : periodVal = periodSlider.slider('value');

            var totalRepayable = Math.round(((((borrow + 195) / 100) * 10) * period) + borrow),
                monthlyPayment = Math.round(totalRepayable / (period * 12)),
                interest = Math.round(totalRepayable - borrow);

            interestNum.html('&pound;' + interest);
            paymentNum.html('&pound;' + monthlyPayment);
            repayableNum.html('&pound;' + (totalRepayable + 195));
        }
    }

    financePage(); //<-- Added this bit which is called a `function call`
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/LWd26/2/

Comment: Thanks this works great. Much appreciated. Again sorry for not explaining my question in detail.